# Inheritance in Core Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

For my homework, we've been tasked with "declare an array of four "regular" College Employees, three Faculty and seven Students. Prompt the user to specify which type of data will be entered (C,F,S) or the option to Quit (Q). While the user continues, accept data entry for the appropriate person. Display an error message if the user enters more than the specified number for each person type. When the user quits, display a report on the screen listing each group of persons under the appropriate heading. If the user has not entered data for one or more types of Person during a session display an appropriate message under the appropriate heading."

```
    Class           | Extends         | Variables
--------------------------------------------------------
    Person          | None            | firstName, lastName, streetAddress, zipCode, phone
    CollegeEmployee | Person          | ssn, salary,deptName
    Faculty         | CollegeEmployee | tenure(boolean)
    Student         | person          | GPA,major
```

After reading the [Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) on inheritance and trolling a bunch of inheritance discussions, I think I've got it right on paper, but would prefer some input before I get elbows deep in code that doesn't work. :)

I'm defining

```
Person[x] = new Student();
```

(or `Faculty` or `CollegeEmployee`).

The `Person` class has all the input fields for a `Person`, and the subclasses have ONLY the additional data (e.g., `major` in the case of `Student`).

When I create the `new Student();` the input fields in BOTH the `People` and `Student` classes will be available to me because `Student` extends `People` and the additional variables defined in `Student` are appended to the definition of `Person` for that instance.

When it comes time to pull data from the array, Java sees it as an array of `Person`, so I need to add logic

```
if Person[x] instanceof Student (or `Faculty` or `CollegeEmployee`)
```

to execute the appropriate actions for the type of `Person`. My sense is that the `instanceof` is acting to override (in this case to append to) what Java knows about the `Person` class on the output side.

Am I missing any critical understandings of this?

Comment: If you need to use `instanceof`, there's a good chance you're doing something wrong...

Comment: Or the assignment constraints are a bit off. You might want to post the exact assignment instructions.

Comment: Person is always a dangerous example for inheritance. When I was a Student I was a CollegeEmployee at the same time. Better than with (not-multiple) inheritance such a situation can be modelled by applying something like 'Roles' to a Person instance.

Comment: @nansen: I think we should reserve specific recommendations until we see the actual requirements. @ the original poster: again, please show us your exact assignment requirements.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels- just posted the assignment requirements. I agree with nansen...but I don't design the assignments. I just get confused by 'em. :)

Comment: Oh, and thanks loads to whomever for the readability edit!

Comment: There's no need for `instanceOf` based on the assignment requirements. The classes will all have their own override of the method used to display themselves. This is what polymorphism is all about.

Comment: I find the assignment to be phrased very vaguely. Should the data entered by the user be used to modify an existing Person in the array or should a new one be created and added to the array? If the array contents should be modified after specifying C,F,S should all Persons of that type be prompted in turn? And what is meant by specified number? The max count of the subtype's properties? Are they to be entered as a comma separated list or what? But from what I believe to understand I think Hovercraft is pointing in the right direction.

Comment: @nansen: Vague is an understatement. My interpretation is that I prompt for the Person subtype and pull in the appropriate, individual data entry fields for that subtype. This data is written to an instance of Person[], and I advance a counter for each instance of a subtype. I continue where the C counter <= 4, F counter <=3 , and S counter <=7, returning an error if I try to enter a fifth (or above) C, etc. The program terminates if I enter Q, and displays a report of all the data entered, with sort and headings by type. I've been exploring polymorphism in the meantime...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not only inheritance,  but polymorphism -  just put code necessary to enter and validate object data in method of object (say: inputMyData()  overriding base method in person, possibly calling method of superclass) - this way you can avoid  instanceof and casting.

Answer (score 3):

First of all address should be rather a separate object.

Secondly, `Student` cannot be a (in)direct descendant of `Person`, as student is a civic-status/job-role (it's even hard to define) and person is a synonyme for human being, which on the other hand is a specie. In other words you cannot say that student **is a** ([inheritance](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=programming%20inheritance&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=9b0c83a130f3bca0&ix=seb&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1600&bih=775)) special case of person, but you can  say that person **has a** ([composition](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sugexp=frgbld&gs_nf=1&tok=01CT6Af2dpJNkyws5czRhg&pq=programming%20inheritance&cp=18&gs_id=z&xhr=t&q=programming+composition&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=programming+compos&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=9b0c83a130f3bca0&ix=seb&ion=1&biw=1600&bih=775)) civic-status of student.

If you take a look at properties of your classes you'll also notice that they do not represent the same thing. Each object should focus on one thing ([single responsibility principle](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sa=X&ei=EA13T_qxH6-Q4gSMpvTrDg&ved=0CCEQvwUoAQ&q=single+responsibility+principle&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=9b0c83a130f3bca0&ix=seb&ion=1&biw=1600&bih=775)), while `Person` object defines first and last name, age etc. (person-related properties) and `CollegeEmployee` defines salary and the name of the department (job-related properties). Totally unrelated properties.

In a nutshell, a person is a really complex object and it's a horrible example for a person who is trying to understand the principles of  the OO-design.

Comment: agreed that `Person` is a bad example, address should be a separate object, and that the object properties make no sense. But as I said, I don't design the assignments, I just get to be baffled by the parameters. I think that's why I'm having so many questions this semester. :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, `instanceof` is to be avoided. The simple thing to do in this case seems to be to make three arrays: a `CollegeEmployee[]`, a `Faculty[]`, and a `Student[]`, rather than lumping them all into one `Person[]` and sorting them out later.

**Original answer below:**

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly, `instanceof` is not necessary.

If you write something like

```
Person bob = new Student();
bob.someAction();
```

where `someAction` is a method defined for `Person` and overridden by `Student`, then Java will call the `Student` version, even if the method is called on a `Person` variable. Dynamic dispatch ensures that method calls always resolve to the version of the method implemented by the actual object type, not the variable type.

Note that this only works if `someAction` is defined as an abstract or concrete method by `Person`. If it's introduced for the first time by `Student`, then you do need to do an explicit cast.

Comment: the assignment specifically states to create *an array*, or one and only one array. You should retract your recommendation for four arrays as this goes against the instructions (and will hamper the demonstration of polymorphism).

Comment: Is that what "declare an array of four "regular" College Employees, three Faculty and seven Students" means? How would you even do that?

Comment: `Person[] people = new Person[14];`